# Signed XAP still shows as publisher unverified

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to publish a signed Lightswitch application for **INTERNAL** use, using a certificate I created myself. I keep getting the publisher unverified prompt when installing the application. In addition to this, when I try to update the application, it tells me there is something wrong with the state of my certificate and will not update. Here are the steps I followed:

- I opened a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt as administrator
- With the makecert tool, I have created a 'root' certificate using the following command line:

> **makecert -n "CN=My Awesome Certificate Authority" -cy authority -a sha1 -sv "My Awesome Certificate Authority Private Key.pvk" -r "My Awesome Certificate Authority.cer"**

- I specified a password for the this certificate
- I have imported this certificate into computer A's *local machine* Trusted Root Certification Authoriaties store.
- With the makecert tool I created a code signing certificate using the following command line:

> **makecert -n "CN=SomeNameHere" -ic "My Awesome Certificate Authority.cer" -iv "My Awesome Certificate Authority Private Key.pvk" -a sha1 -sky exchange -pe -sv "SomeNameHere Private Key.pvk" "SomeNameHere.cer"**

- I did not specify a password for the code signing certificate
- With the pvk2pfx tool I executed to following command line:

> **pvk2pfx -pvk "SomeNameHere Private Key.pvk" -spc "SomeNameHere.cer" -pfx "SomeNameHere.pfx"**

- I copied the pfx file to a development machine, and specified in the Lightswitch  publish wizard that it should use this code signing certificate to sign the silverlight client.
- I published the application as a 3 tier desktop app.
- I opened internet explorer 9 and navigated to the lightswitch applications url, and clicked Install AppName.

I get the following prompt:

> [image]

I get the following error when I try to update

> [image]

Are there any requirements for the code signing certificate, as far as the CN goes? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in the HTML Client Preview 2. It occurs because the wrong xap file is signed. For some reason there now exists two xap files on the server, one in Web\app.xap and one is Client\web\app.xap the former being signed and the latter being unsigned. As you have upgraded to the HTML Client Preview 2 the latter file is now being used as you must navigate to the [http://webhost/webapp/Client/] directory in order to install your application. the fix below makes sure that the correct xap file is signed. I presume this bug will be solved in a similar manner perhaps once the final build of Lightswitch HTML Client is upon us.

You can solve it by doing the following

Open the following file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v3.0\Publish\v1.7\
>   Microsoft.LightSwitch.Publish.targets

Search for the following string "XapSignTask" and on the 2nd occurance find the line that reads:

XapFileName="$(_ApplicationDir)\Web\%(_ClientXap.FileName)%(_ClientXap.Extension)"

change it to:

XapFileName="$(_ApplicationDir)Client\Web\%(_ClientXap.FileName)%(_ClientXap.Extension)"